# ssis script task to create folders in Sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis

I am trying to create an SSIS package that gets a folder tree structure from a remote SQL DB and recreates that structure in a document library in Sharepoint.

I tried to (hard) code a Script Task to create just one folder but I'm getting this error:
http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/1386/helpel.png

After running only a part of this script:

```
Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime.dll

public void Main()
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://spdemo.example.com/");
        clientContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "password", "SPDEMO");
        Web rootWeb = clientContext.Web;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

I've scoured the internet for solutions, but haven't found something that works for me.

So basically i need to find out how to:

1. create a folder
2. populate it with sub-folders
3. Copy files in bitestreams from SQL to Sharepoint, all in SSIS

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Vlad Ardelean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that in order to reference a DLL in a SSIS Script Task it first has to be [strong named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx)

Instead, I have found an easier way to create folders and upload files:

```
public void CreateFolder(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        request.Method = "MKCOL";
        HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }

public void UploadDocument(byte[] file, string destinationName)
    {
        byte[] buffer = file;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(destinationName);
        request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        writer.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }
```

url : represents the url path of the folder you want to create

```
http://spsite.host.com/DocLib/FolderToCreate
```

destinationName: path + document name

```
http://spsite.host.com/DocLib/FolderToCreate/DocToCreate.docx
```

Comment: Good one! And I have also found that, after you strong name it, you need to have in the GAC. I am not 100% sure that if a Script Task's referenced assembly should be deployed to GAC, but if you dont that, it works! if you dont, it throws Assembly Load failure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running your code from a stand-alone windows application written in C# in Visual Studio?
If I get errors in SSIS, my preference is to test that code thoroughly in Visual Studio and then port it to a script task in SSIS.

If you haven't done folder creation and file copy to SharePoint, the below links might help.

1. Create a folder - http://thingsthatshouldbeeasy.blogspot.in/2009/09/how-to-add-folder-to-sharepoint-list.html
2. You can do the create folder step recursively untill you have created the destination tree structure.
3. Copy Files - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470176.aspx

I dont understand what you mean by copy file in bitestreams from SQL. If you want to read binary data from SQLServer via ADO.Net use `System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary`

Read the data from SQL server to a stream and write to a temp file, copy that temp file from local to SP. Or you may even write the data in a stream to SP directly without a temp file.

Comment: I was thinking of trying the code in a stand alone application, but was hoping to solve it in the SSIS script.
also, the link you provided in #1 is for adding folders in lists, and not document library, and I am trying to use the Client Model to achieve this.

Comment: I just tried the code in a stand-alone console application and I can get it to work, but when I moved the code inside the SSIS Task I keep getting that nasty error.
Right now I am clueless

Comment: I noticed that I get the error after having only this line of code in the SSIS Script Task:

    `ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://spdemo.example.com");`

Comment: I am afraid I have no experience with the ClientModel. But you may cehck the referenced version of the dlls containing Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll and 
Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime.dll. That error message looks like the referenced dlls could not be loaded. Although it does not seem any specific, thats what I doubt. I might be wrong. good luck.